# Shutdown Windows 7 with C# using Visual Studio 2013 and Arduino serial/COM port

Tags: c#, if-statement, visual-studio-2013, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to create a program that will shutdown my system when a specific string or character is sent from my Arduino. When I debug the program and send string "S" from my Arduino, the console application simply closes without a printout.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Arduino_Test
{
class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 9600;
        myport.PortName = "COM5";
        myport.Open();

            string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
            string s = "S";
            if(data_rx == s)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
               var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /f /t 0");
               psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
               psi.UseShellExecute = false;
               Process.Start(psi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect something is wrong within the if statement. Furthermore I am in need of help regarding Visual Studio 2013, I am unfamiliar with C# and the application. My project is a console application, is it possible to create a windows forms application using the same code? I am under experienced in this field and your patience is appreciated.

Comment: Your program will terminate after any data is received..  You've not allowed for it to send anything else

Comment: Always make breakpoints in Visual Studio to see if you reach your code (in your case under the if)

Comment: How can I stop it from terminating after data is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to define some new terminal state, but lets pretend that it should run forever. If that is the case, simply put your read code in a loop.

```
while(true) {
        string data_rx = myport.ReadLine();
        string s = "S";
        if(data_rx == s)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(data_rx);
           var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /f /t 0");
           psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
           psi.UseShellExecute = false;
           Process.Start(psi);
        }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you, but I am still having problems with my if statement as described in my answer/response above.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the if statement, what does the value come back as when the shutdown signal is sent?